# Отсутствие тире в конструкции типа «подлежащее-существительное — сказуемое-существительное»

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Стоит ли ставить тире:

1. Перед именем собственным в предложении "Интересный чувак Митя".
2. После имени собственного в предложении "Митя зато интересный чувак".

Если не стоит, каким правилом пунктуации это подтверждается в предложениях, подлежащее и сказуемое которых выражено существительным?

Comment: Опечаток/ошибок перебор. Проверьте текст, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В зависимости от интонации возможны варианты:

***Интересный чувак Митя.

Интересный чувак – Митя.***

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91) (Розенталь)

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
> <...>
> 6) если сказуемое предшествует подлежащему: *Прекрасный человек **Иван Иванович!*** (Г.); *Славное место эта **долина!*** (Л.); *Живописный народ **индийцы** (Гонч.); *Неплохой ученик этот **мальчик.***
>
> Постановка тире в этом случае подчеркивает интонационное деление предложения на два состава: *Славные люди — **соседи** мои!* (П.)... Психологический курьёз — моя **мать*** (Ч.); *Ловкая штучка — **умишко** человеческий* (М. Г.)...

2. И в этом случае рулит интонация (ведь даже в правиле написано "**обычно**", а значит, не всегда):

***Митя зато интересный чувак.

Митя зато – интересный чувак.***

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
> <...>
> 4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, иногда – наречие, союз, частица: ...***Сергеев** теперь известный **художник**; **Пихта** тоже **дерево** смолистое; **Март** только **начало** весны.*